# Как сериализовать объект содержащий объект BufferedImage?

Tags: java, сериализация

Я создал класс `MyClass1`. Он содержит поле `myAbout` класса `BufferedImage`. Для того, чтобы сериализовать объект класса `MyClass1` я имплементирую в нем `Serializable`. Но, т.к. класс `MyClass1` содержит поле  `myAbout` класса `BufferedImage`, то нужно в классе `BufferedImage` тоже имплементировать `Serializable`, как это сделать?

Comment: Вы пробовали в BufferedImage реализовать интерфейс Serializable ?

Comment: Но ведь это готовый джававский класс. Я поэтому и спрашиваю: как в нём  реализовать интерфейс Serializable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого в Java существует интерфейс `java.io.Externalizable`, который расширяет интерфейс `java.io.Serializable`, и даёт Вам контроль над сериализацией/десереализацией вложенных объектов. Таким образом можете как Вам угодно сериализовать вложенный в Ваш класс BufferedImage.

Comment: Переписал класс под java.io.Externalizable. Но в результате получаю исключение: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Comment: Насколько я разобрался для Externalizable всё-равно что сериализовать. Но в результате получаю ту же ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 способа, первый отмечен @zolt, но он не раскрыт в деталях (думаю он раскроет несложные детали экстернализации), есть еще второй способ, технически делается так:

1. Пишем классик `MyBufferedImage extends BufferedImage implements Serializable {}`
2. В этом классе пишете 2 метода: `private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)` и `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)`, которые и будут отвечать за реализацию сериализации вашего класса `MyBufferedImage`
3. Профит

Comment: К сожалению в деталях я застрял. Не получилось решить эту задачу с помощью Externalizable. Над вашим вариантом я думал, но не хотелось создавать дополнительный класс (если можно без этого обойтись). Но видимо без этого никак. Наверное воспользуюсь вашим способом